# when running playonlinux I get the error "PlayOnLinux cannot find 7z."

Tags: playonlinux

When trying to run Linux I get the error message:

> PlayOnLinux cannot find 7z.
>
> You should install it to use PlayOnLinux

How do I install "7z"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply open the software centre, search for 7z, click on 7zip, and click install; to make it even easier click:

[image: Install via the software center]

and then click on the

[image: orange software]

Comment: In a perfect world wouldn't 7zip be a listed dependancy and thus install with playonlinux?

Comment: @Jason, yes.. file a bug report suggesting that.

Answer (score 6):

Open term and type this:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Worked for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Type the following :

```
sudo apt-get install xterm unrar-free p7zip-full
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This answer includes extra packages that are in no way associated with what is being asked.  Could you explain why xterm and unrar are needed for PlayOnLinux?; by editing your answer. Another option would be to delete.  Please do not be offended to better understand how Ask Ubuntu works invest some time in the help centre and about features of this site.

Answer (score -2):

This should help I suggest go to this URL and install accordingly,

http://ashu-geek.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-install-7-zip-file-archiver-on.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.